# WPF Document viewer export to PDF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, documentviewer

Hi I'm using a WPF Document viewer to view a document 
Is there any way to save the document as PDF ?

```
<DocumentViewer Name="documentViewer" />
```

I'm using [WPFReports](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com) to generate a report.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, no, you can't. However you can render DocumentViewer to XPS and then that one to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label>
  <Hyperlink Click="lnkSelectDocument_Click">
    <Label Content="{Binding ShortFielName}">
    </Label>
  </Hyperlink> 
</Label>


private void lnkSelectDocument_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  try {
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    string path = "d:\\test.doc";
    Uri pdf = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pdf.LocalPath;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
  } catch (Exception error) {
    MessageBox.Show("Could not open the file.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK,
      MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  }
}
```